# Client Python close my TCP connection without socket.close()

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, client

I am developing a TCP client on Python, and I have the next problem. I connect with the server, I send it some data, it response me with the data expected but after this the my own application (client) send a [FIN, ACK] (checked with wireshark). Here is my client app:

```
try:
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.bind((my_ip,my_port))
    sock.connect((sendAddress,sendPort))
    sock.send(joinRequest)
    joinResponse = sock.recv(18)
    print joinResponse

except socket.timeout:
    sock.close()
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the exception handling for socket.timeout?

Comment: This code receives the response and  prints it out. Then there's no more code, perhaps your application ends, which will close the socket? What do you want your application to do ?

Comment: goncalopp: It happens the same, close the connection after send the ack to the server. nos: I want to keep the TCP connection alive because it has to recive and send data all the time. It is a P2P application, and the servent(server wich I want to connect) send me the acceptation to connect the network, and after that, it has to be connect all the time... I have tried with SO_KEEPALIVE but my client closes the connection as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default behavior of SocketServer, accept a connection, get the request, and then close the connection.

The simple way will be to use while loop to keep it connected, You can also use sock.settimeout to tune the timeout

Comment: But the problem is that in wireshark I see that the first [FIN,ACK] is send it by the client, not the server...

Comment: @AlvaroGarciadelaVilla what DevC meant is that the [FIN,ACK] is sent by the client because the program terminates, so the socket is closed automatically.